# Jasper Reports with Visualize.js: call to inputcontrols stalls intermittently?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, visualize

We have a SaaS application running with an AngularJS front end and Jasper Reports integrated using the Visualize.js framework. We are seeing an issue where after the Jasper server has been running for a while, the call to get the input controls will stall in the browser. The strange thing is that all the other calls proceeding it (auth, resourcessearch, etc.) return just fine. It seems to be only the inputcontrols that stalls. When this happens, we see no errors in the logs, memory & CPU on the Jasper server are fine, etc. To fix the problem, we are generally forced to bounce the Jasper server.

Has anyone experienced this problem? Any advice?

A little more info:

- Jasper Professional version 6.1.1
- Seeing the problem in all supported browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome)
- Problem happens both with a single user and with concurrent users
- Input controls will *sometimes* return after 8-10 MINUTES if we wait
  long enough (with Apache timeout cranked to 15 minutes)